# For - loop over rows and columns, filling an empty dataframe, depending on values of another dataframe (r)

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I try to fill an empty dataframe (pen_NA) with values of 1 - 3
depending on the height of the values in another data frame (pen_2).
There is no error message, but the code does not do the job either.
Are there some hints?

My data frame looks like this:
Trait1  Trait2 ...
Plant.nr.1  value   value  ...
Plant.nr.2  value   value  ...
...

```
for (j in 1:ncol(pen_NA)) {

 for (i in which(is.na(pen_NA[,j]))) { 
  
    if (pen_2[i,j] > 3) 
  {pen_NA[i,j]== 1}
  else if (pen_2[i,j] < 3)
  {pen_NA[i,j]== 2}
  else if (pen_2[i,j] == 3)  
  {pen_NA[i,j]== 3}
  else
  pen_NA[i,j]== pen_NA[i,j]
 }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's impute missing values of Trait1 with 1 if Trait2 is 1 or with 2 if Trait2 is zero:

```r
library(tidyverse)
traits_a <- tibble(Plant_id = seq(4), Trait1 = c(NA,NA,0,0))
traits_a
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>   Plant_id Trait1
#>      <int>  <dbl>
#> 1        1     NA
#> 2        2     NA
#> 3        3      0
#> 4        4      0
traits_b <- tibble(Plant_id = seq(4),Trait2 = c(1,0,0,1))
traits_b
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>   Plant_id Trait2
#>      <int>  <dbl>
#> 1        1      1
#> 2        2      0
#> 3        3      0
#> 4        4      1

traits_a %>%
  left_join(traits_b) %>%
  mutate(
    Trait1 = case_when(
      !is.na(Trait1) ~ Trait1,
      Trait2 == 1 ~ 1,
      Trait2 == 0 ~ 2
    )
  )
#> Joining, by = "Plant_id"
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>   Plant_id Trait1 Trait2
#>      <int>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1        1      1      1
#> 2        2      2      0
#> 3        3      0      0
#> 4        4      0      1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>